# How do I add the author's image in a view?

Tags: views, media, users

I want to add the player's photo shown in the user profile, in a view that shows the following data.

[image]

The view shows a list of nodes. The "Player Name" field shows the author of the node.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using a relationship in your view.

Under advanced in your view -> Relationships -> add and choose Content: Author.
You should then have the option to add the user picture in your Fields section.

Comment: Thx a lot , i fixed my problem. it's working

Answer (score 0):

@Q10 absolutely right,

Relationships
Content: Author
(author) User: Profile

but there is another way by hooking user profile to show each and every individual fields
user-profile.tpl.php
For printing fields
Condition: if((arg(0)=='user') && is_numeric(arg(1)))
          {
             render your fields
}